# Maven dependency resolution

Tags: dependencies, repository, maven

I am creating two projects with Maven.

Project1 and Project2.

I have a dependency with jar1.jar to create Project1.jar. Also, I have dependency with Project1.jar to create Project2.war. I'm providing "provided" scope for Project1.jar dependency entry in Project2. Also, I am giving "compile" scope dependency for jar1.jar dependency entry in Project1.

What I am getting is, the jar1.jar is also getting included inside the Project2.war. But jar1.jar is provided by the environment at which Project2.war gets loaded.

Comment: Yes, that is right I think. Basically your Project1.jar does not include the dependency in it. Basically it maps the jar based on pom.xml with repository specified in the settings.xml. So, you project2 is depends on project1 and project1 is depends on jar1. therefore project2 depends on jar1. Its transitive :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Mohamed Saligh. Basically my Project1.jar is an executable server like application and it has the jar1.jar in it's manifest. Then I think the Project2.war running from the Project1.jar server need not contain jar1.jar, right? Because the Project1.jar application has got jar1.jar in it's classpath(manifest entry).

Answer (score 0):

You could do a couple of things.

You could make the scope of `jar1.jar` as `provided` in `pom.xml` of `Project1`.   Dependencies with `provided` scope are included in compile classpath.

You could explicitly exclude `jar1.jar` when declaring the dependency for `Project1`.